# The Definition of Derivative of function in Analysis on Manifold by Munkres

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

so i've been reading Analysis on Manifold by Munkres and in page 43, there is a definition of derivative of $f :\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which is:

"Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$. We say that $f$ is **differentiable** at a if there is an n by m matrix such that
$$ \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - B.h}{|h|} \rightarrow0 \text{ as } h\rightarrow 0$$
...
"

Is that definition equivalent to

"Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$. $f: A\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $a$, if for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that

$$\bigg |\frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - B.h}{|h|} \bigg | < \varepsilon \text{ whenever } 0<|h| <\delta$$

"
(with $|\cdot|$ denote sup norm in $\mathbb{R}^m$)?

Im sorry if the question is too elementary.

Comment: Yes. For $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $x\to0\iff |x|\to0$, as you can verify.

Comment: The answer given is good, but I just wish to make the following remark: there is actually no need for $|\cdot|$ to be the sup-norm (on $\Bbb{R}^m$). This is because $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, and it is a standard theorem that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent (i.e give rise to the same topology). As a result of this, you can verify that if $f$ is differentiable with respect to a particular norm, it will be differentiable with respect to any other equivalent norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version should still have "[...] is differentiable at $a,$ if **there is an $n$ by $m$ matrix $B$ such that** for every $\varepsilon > 0$[...]"

Otherwise, yes, they are equivalent simply by the definition of limits of functions $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n.$ (along with the equivalence on $\mathbb{R}^d$ of the sup-norm, euclidean norm, and the manhattan norm -- whichever you might use for the definition)

Answer (score 0):

On p.4 Munkres introduces two norms on $\mathbb R^n$: The Euclidean norm $\lVert \phantom{-} \rVert$ and the supremum norm $\lvert \phantom{-}  \rvert$. On p.25 he uses these norms to define the Euclidean metric $d(x,y) = \lVert x - y \rVert$ and the supremum metric $d(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert$.

Define $g(h) = \dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a) -B \cdot h}{\lvert h \rvert} \in \mathbb R^m$. The denominator $\lvert h \rvert$ involves the supremum norm, but this is not essential, we could also take the Euclidean norm (as Munkres mentions on p.43) or more generally any other norm. In fact, it can be shown  that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent which means that concerning convergence it is irreleavnt which norm we choose.

What is the meaning of $g(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$? This has been defined by Munkres for arbitrary functions between metric spaces on p.28. His definition is based on open sets, but he shows that it is equivalent to the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition of limits.

Thus $g(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ is *by definition* equivalent to the following:

For each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\dfrac{\lvert f(a+h) - f(a) -B \cdot h \rvert }{\lvert h \rvert} = \lvert g(h)\rvert = \lvert g(h) - 0 \rvert < \epsilon$$
whenever
$$0 < \lvert h - 0 \rvert = \lvert h \rvert < \delta .$$